# Seller and Buyers Own Comments (Commerce Communicae)

Tags: views, commerce, comments

I would like to have a way for my seller/author (author of node) and my buyer/user (not author of node) to communicate.

First, I have looked at the comments. If I allowed buyers to only start one comment and seller only able to reply to that buyer's one thread.. I envision buyer adding comment and seller only being able to reply to that comment. the seller would also see comments from other buyers; one thread per buyer so the conversations are grouped by buyer; for the seller to see. The buyer would see only their initial starting comment and any replies from the seller.

If used a view to contextually filter for same exact node and contextually filter for logged users authored nodes. basically showing the same node if logged user is seller. then I just use view mode to display the comments only. this results in the seller/author seeing entire comments.. in this case id only have to limit buyers/users to making one comment thread and the seller/author view would be 'finished'

How do I limit buyers/users from posting only one initial tread that buyer and seller reply back and forth. so from sellers view, they see buyers only once in comment list and the conversation there.

For the buyer I haven't been able to use view block to make correct relationships to get the buyers initial comment thread as well as the authors replies to it..

1. Should I use two views and better filters and relationships, (or
   even 1 view?)
2. Should I make new content types or entities instead
   of using comments? (id hope to leverage the comment form, and email
   alerts and rest of comment stuff instead of making new framework
3. Should I consider other modules or organic groups? (again comments is
   so close id hate to reinvent the wheel.
4. Should I consider livechat module and have it make a separate chat channel per item, per buyer/seller?

**Edited** 
It seems to me that if I can keep user making only 1 comment, if I can target the start of the thread I can then say grab only the buyers comment starting tread.

**Added**
So tried entity construction kit and was further than comments is already from my goal. used entity reference field so in node edit you saw a message text field; didnt want that.

Also tried some modules for buyers to only start one comment thread. onecomment, one_comment_only... did not have what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you revise your OP and keep the terms the same as in the title, ie Buyer and Seller throughout the OP? It's a bit confusing when you say users, are you referring to buyers or sellers?

Comment: users are buyers. users are not authors (of the specific node).
and what do you mean by OP?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [commerce_message](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_message)? In Kickstart 2, we created an order commenting system, where buyers and sellers could leave messages for each other and the system could also leave notes about the history.